# Inside foreach() loop display elements uniquely

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

This is my database structure.

table: memberships

```
mbs_id | mbs_color | mbs_name
   1   |    red    | Standard
   2   |  yellow   | Premium
   3   |   green   | Elite
   4   |   blue    | Ultimate
```

table: advertisements

```
ad_id  | ad_memberships
   1   | 1,2          
   2   | 1,2,3          
   3   | 1,3            
   4   | 2,3
```

I have a code which displays colors in for each loop according to the values in `ad_memberships`. This means that if `ad_membership` contains 1,2 then it shows red and yellow color side by side in square boxes. This job is well accomplished with the following code. But what I now want to do is when I hove these boxes it shows the membership names as in `title` attribute. With membership names I mean `mbs_name`. For example, if red box is hovered it will say `Standard` if yellow box is hovered it will say `Premium` etc. These colored boxes are displayed from `<span class="membership-indicator">`. What should be added here?

Code:

```
<div class="ads-container">
  <?php
    $cat = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ads_category");
    $cat-> execute();

    $i = 0;
    while($s = $cat->fetch()){
      $ads = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(memberships.mbs_color) AS colors FROM advertisements
                                INNER JOIN memberships ON FIND_IN_SET(memberships.mbs_id, advertisements.ad_memberships)
                                LEFT JOIN ads_category ON advertisements.ad_category = ads_category.ac_id
                                WHERE ad_credits >= ac_credits AND ad_category = :cat AND ad_status = 'active'
                                GROUP BY advertisements.ad_id");
      $ads-> bindValue(':cat', $s['ac_id']);
      $ads-> execute();

      while($a = $ads->fetch()){ 
         $mbs_colors = explode(',', $a['colors']);
  ?>
      <div class="" <?php if($i++ != 0){ echo "style='margin-top: 30px'"; } ?>>
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $ac_category; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="adcover">
          <div class="ad-title">
            <a href="surf.php?ad=<?php echo $a['ad_id']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $a['ad_title']; ?></a>
          </div>
          <div class="ad-footer-two">
            <?php foreach($mbs_colors as $color){   ?>
              <span class="membership-indicator" style="background: <?php echo $color; ?>; margin-top: 4px" title="<?php echo $a['mbs_name']; ?>"></span>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <?php } } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can get the `mbs_name` data the same way you get the colors:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(memberships.mbs_name) AS names
```

In your `while` loop, you can then explode them equivalently again:

```
$mbs_names = explode(',', $a['names']);
```

Then you might add both arrays together as one:

```
$membershipData = array_map(function($color, $name){
    return (object)['color' => $color, 'name' => $name];
}, $mbs_colors, $mbs_names);
```

Finally you can iterate over this newly created array and print out the data:

```
<?php foreach($membershipData as $membership){   ?>
    <span class="membership-indicator" style="background: <?php echo $membership->color; ?>; margin-top: 4px" title="<?php echo $membership->name; ?>"></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Perfect.. exactly what I was looking for :)